# TypeORM + Express deployed to firebase cloud function cannot connect to Cloud SQL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, typeorm

I tried to deploy a typeorm express server to Cloud Function for Firebase.

ormconfig:

```json
{
  type: "postgres",
  username: [username],
  password: [password],
  database: [dbname],
  extra: {
    socketPath: `/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]`,
  },
  synchronize: false,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: true,
}
```

(values inside brackets are placeholders)

After deployed, the log complains about

> TypeORM connection error:  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

I don't understand why the DB address turned to `127.0.0.1`? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set the `host` value to `/cloudsql/project:region:instance` along with the `socketPath`

Comment: From tutorials I've read, the unix socket is a recommended way to connect to Cloud SQL. If `host` is set, would `socketPath` be used?

Comment: Indeed, unix sockets are [mentioned in the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#connecting_to) as a way to connect to Cloud SQL. I am unsure how TypeORM works behind the scenes, but I found this other users [1](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3263#issuecomment-541591106) [2](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2614#issuecomment-667028124) that stated that doing what I suggested worked for them.

Answer (score 1):

`host` should be specified in you `ormconfig.json`, if you did not use a default port for you db instance, `port` also required. And please make sure your ormconfig.json is valid json format

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test",
  "database": "test",
  "host": "localhost"
}
```